# <canvas> rect path - how?

Tags: html, canvas

I'm wondering how can I draw a path of a rect (like how I can using lineTo()).

Comment: What do you mean by "the path of a rect"? Its outline?

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen The path you can draw to the canvas but doesn't appear until you stroke() or fill() it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what the problem here is. Doesn't the [`rect`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#complex-shapes-%28paths%29) method do exactly that?

Comment: Thanks! didnt saw that method... I feel so dumb :P

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the rect() function is different from the strokeRect() and fillRect() functions. These two functions draw on the canvas *immediately* without the need for beginPath() or stroke()/fill() calls. For example this draws a rectangle on to the canvas:

context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(5,5,100,100);